# Android shared preference error, while executing AsyncTask?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, sharedpreferences

I am successfully storing the values and retrieving but when i am using a condition like this

```
String checkpassword = "";
GlobalData GD = new GlobalData(getApplicationContext());
checkpassword = this.getpassword(GD);
if (checkpassword.equalsequalsIgnoreCase("") || checkpassword  == null
                || checkpassword.equalsIgnoreCase("null")){
   ShowCustomPopup();
}
```

Popup appears even if i am having string inside the shared preference not in all android devices but in 4.4.4 devices this happens frequently is there any solution for this the complete method is below Thanks 
Note : When debugging application it works correctly no issues.

This is my method to store values

```
public void setpassword(GlobalData GD){
String password = "password";
GD.SetPassword(password);
GD.CommitUpdate;
}
```

This is my method to get value

```
public String getpassword(GlobalData GD){
return GD.GetPassword();
}
```

This is my class to store values and commit

```
public class GlobalData {

    SharedPreferences prefs = null;
    SharedPreferences SetPrefsObj = null;
    Editor editor;

    public GlobalData(Context ctx)
    {
    prefs = Prefs.get(ctx);
    SetPrefsObj = SetPrefs.get(ctx);
    editor = SetPrefsObj.edit();
    }

    public String GetPassword() 
    { 
      return this.prefs.getString("password",""); 
    }

    public void SetPassword(String Str_Value){ 
      editor.putString("password",Str_Value); 
    }

    public void CommitUpdate(){
        editor.commit();
    }
```

Comment: whats the error?.....

Comment: Is `SharedPreferences` if your custom class because `SharedPreferences.get(Context)` method not available in [Doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) ??

Comment: Are these lines correct `prefs = Prefs.get(ctx);` and `SetPrefsObj = SetPrefs.get(ctx);`?

Comment: Did you debug? And when have you called `setpassword`? You are creating new instance of `GlobalData`, you sure it has old data?

Comment: @MagicalPhoenixϡ Yes, when i debug i am getting the value(there is no issue while debugging)

Comment: what do you get in String checkPassword? is that correct as well?

Comment: @Gopic.s: `Prefs.get` and `SetPrefs.get` return same `SharedPreference` ? i mean both preference name is same return from `get` method ?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK this is my common class to save and retrieve values it works good in all condition except the above

Comment: @Gopic.s: because you are calling `SetPrefsObj.edit()` method on `SetPrefs` but `getString` from `prefs`

Comment: I have Google d a lot and spent lot time on this cannot find any solution for this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GetTask is my AsyncTask which was executed while executing AsyncTask to get the values from shared preference(i am also checking password from the same preference set) with the password popup check, i am not sure with this but it might be an issue accessing same preference might give such issue in android

previously i was doing password check along with the AsyncTask now i am checking it before Executing the Task.

```
String checkpassword = "";
GlobalData GD = new GlobalData(getApplicationContext());
checkpassword = this.getpassword(GD);
if (checkpassword.equalsequalsIgnoreCase("") || checkpassword  == null
                || checkpassword.equalsIgnoreCase("null")){
   ShowCustomPopup();
}

new GetTask(this, this, null).execute();

class GetTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, String>
    {
        Context context;
        Activity actvity;

        GetTask(Context context, Activity act, String userid) {
            this.context = context;
            actvity = act;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            imgSpinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            imgSpinner.startAnimation(animRotate);
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Object... params) {

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {

                    tv_text1.setText(GD.GetLastID);
                    tv_text2.setText(PD.GetLatestID);

                }
            });

            return "";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            imgSpinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            imgSpinner.clearAnimation();
        }
    }
```

I am not sure of it but checking password popup before the the AsyncTask fixed the issue..

Note: i am also reading another preference data in AsyncTask

Answer (score 1):

```
if (checkpassword  == null && ("".equalsequalsIgnoreCase(checkpassword)  
                || "null".equalsIgnoreCase(checkpassword))){
   ShowCustomPopup();
}
```

Use above statement it's works for all devices.Your checking `checkpassword  == null` as second statement,its not good,because object checking always should be on first and then only you have to do another thing.